# Custom fields in array not posting when containing numbers

Tags: php, arrays, post

I have a PHP form where I need to search custom fields. If the custom field contains a number, it won't show as posted, however a string of letters will.

If I `var_dump($_POST['customfield'])` it displays the field, key and value. I attempted a `foreach` loop to count how many fields post. It returns `0` if I only post with numbers.

```php
$postCustomFields = $_POST['customfield'];

foreach ($postCustomFields as $key => $cfield) {
        if ($postCustomFields[$key][$cfield] != null) {
            $customfields++;
        }
    }
```

Fields are named `customfield[0]`. Inside the brackets is the field ID. I just need a way to have the numeric value be usable and count in the `customfields` array.

`var_dump($_POST['customfield'])` output. The key is the field ID:

```
array(9) {
  [3]=>
  string(1) "5"
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are confused with array reference. You have array with `array [key => value]`, but you try to access data like `array[key][value]` and there are not exists.

In your case your `$postCustomFields[$key]` will contains your ID `5`

Comment: Doh! Thank you! I changed it to `$postCustomFields[$key]` and it works.